# How to enforce calling convention?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, calling-convention

I'm trying to write code, which enforces specific calling convention:

```
int __cdecl add(int a, int b) 
{
    return a + b;
}

int main() 
{
    int c = add(5, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

`cdecl` is supposed to force pushing all parameters through stack. Project is built in release mode, but with disabled optimizations (otherwise optimizer would optimize out the whole code, as it has no side effects). But regardless of what convention do I choose, I always get the following assembly:

```
 5: 
 6: int main() 
 7: {
00007FF640871020  sub         rsp,38h  
 8:     int c = add(5, 8);
00007FF640871024  mov         edx,8  
00007FF640871029  mov         ecx,5  
00007FF64087102E  call        add (07FF640871000h)  
00007FF640871033  mov         dword ptr [c],eax  
 9:     return 0;
00007FF640871037  xor         eax,eax  
10: }
00007FF640871039  add         rsp,38h  
00007FF64087103D  ret
```

As far as I know, this corresponds to MS `fastcall` calling convention.

I also tried to switch compilation options for this project to use `cdecl` by default, but this changed nothing.

Is there a way to enforce specific calling convention? IDE/compiler is VS.

Comment: It is the [x64 calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention).  The `__cdecl` calling convention is an x86 implementation detail, in code built to x64 has no effect at all.

Comment: And in 32 bit builds, the names are mangled differently, even in C code, so the linker will catch it.